# mosquitto-client obtain refused connection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to use MQTT protocol using mosquitto library.

First of all, I want to do some test installing mosquitto-clients

```
 sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
```

This program provides two "method":

- mosquitto_pub
- mosquitto_sub

Following [**this**](http://michaelconnors.net/article/462/hello-mqtt) instructions I'm trying to submit new topic:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t newtopic/test
```

using default host/port [localhost/1883].

I obtain:

```
Error: Connection refused
```

Is too generic as error.. can anyone help me?
Could be is a firewall problem? In this case, how can I check if is this the problem?

I'm using linux ubuntu ( 3.8.0-42-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu)

**nb** same behaviour writing custom program using libmosquitto.

Comment: If you want to use your computer as MQTT broker, you should install mosquitto. It is MQTT daemon.

Comment: watta idiot! I've unistall it and I forget to re-install it! thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem but please delete this question. It won't help anyone in the future.

Comment: The source code of the utilities is with that of the broker in the package at [mosquitto.org](http://mosquitto.org)

Comment: If I want to post in a server, do I need of mosquitto deamon running inside server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default host:port combination for mosquitto_pub/sub is localhost:1883. If you do not have a broker running on your local computer then it will not be able to connect of course.

The solution is to either run the broker on your local computer, or to tell the utilities where to connect. For example:

```
mosquitto_sub -t newtopic/test -h test.mosquitto.org
```

Answer (score 28):

Just edit Mosquitto configuration file ( `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf` ) adding these lines...
`allow_anonymous true`
`listener 1883 0.0.0.0`

... and restart Mosquitto (as service or not).
`$ sudo service mosquitto restart`

or
`$ mosquitto --verbose --config-file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf`

As informed [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html), since v1.7 (2022) `allow_anonymous` defaulted to `false`.
It is also useful to check log messages ( `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` ).

Finally, run Mosquitto subscriber/publisher using `--host` (`-h`) parameter and the host IP address (get if from `ifconfig` or `ip -color addr` command).

Answer (score 13):

None of the other answers worked for me. In my case, I had upgraded from mosquitto 1.X to mosquitto 2.0, which requires a new configuration to be added to your `mosquitto.conf`:

```
listener 1883
```

For clients other than localhost to connect (ie, via Docker)

Comment: For me the "right answer" is somewhat distributed over several posts here. I had to modify the configuration file located at `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and added two lines: `listener 1883` (which was not enough) plus `allow_anonymous true`. And don't forget to restart the service!

Comment: all the clues I needed to get this working were in the mosquitto logs (in my case, easily viewable in docker). The logs clearly say that connections are only available locally, so go edit your mosquitto.conf file. A great example of useful logging

Answer (score 9):

For future googlers:

You can use a public host as mentioned above, but to start a *local* mosquitto broker, first make sure you have installed `mosquitto` in addition to `mosquitto_sub`. You can then start up the mosquitto broker by simply running the following:

```
mosquitto
```

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same issue, for me it was in upgrading `mosquitto` for mqtt v5 support:

```
$ mosquitto --version
mosquitto version 2.0.14
mosquitto is an MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.
```

However, the upgraded broker no longer supported anonymous connections:

```
$ mosquitto_pub -t mytopic -m "Hello World"
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

This is probably a better default, but less friendly when experimenting.
To configure the broker to allow anonymous connections:

```
$ cat /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/standard.conf
listener 1883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true

$ sudo systemctl restart mosquitto.service
```

Then, hey presto :

```
$ mosquitto_pub -t mytopic -m "Hello World"
```

Comment: I was moving a config over form ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 and missed that mosquitto versions updated.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have installed only mosquitto clients on your system and not installed mosquitto on your system. please execute below command to install the MQTT Broker.

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```

source:
[connection attempt failed bytesofgigabytes.com](http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/mqtt/installing-mqtt-broker-on-windows/)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure Your mosquitto service installed and correctly running.

for install : `sudo apt-get install mosquitto`

after install : `sudo service mosquitto stop` , `sudo service mosquitto start`

Answer (score 1):

I had setup a username and password for my broker. Therefore had to use that while using mosquitto sub:

```
mosquitto_sub -u username -P password -t newtopic/test -h test.mosquitto.org
```

Comment: How did you setup username/password for the broker?

Comment: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-username-password-example/#:~:text=You%20will%20need%20to%20copy,to%20set%20the%20password_file%20path. You van follow this tutorial